# Uniform convergence of the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{((x+\pi)n)^2}$ for $x \in (-\pi,\pi)$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, uniform-convergence

I was checking for the uniform convergence of the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{((x+\pi)n)^2}$ for $x \in (-\pi,\pi)$.

How to think of a bound for $\frac{1}{((x+\pi)n)^2}$ where $x \in (-\pi,\pi)$?, we know $(x+\pi) \in (0,2\pi)$ and for $1\leq(x+\pi)<2\pi $ we have $\frac{1}{((x+\pi)n)^2} < \frac{1}{4\pi^2 n ^2}$ and we are done by the Weierstrass criterion but for $x \in (0,1)$ we have $\frac{1}{((x+\pi)n)^2} > \frac{1}{n^2}$, so its not true for all $x \in (0,2\pi)$ . ?

The true for all $x$ is required as per the definition of Uniform convergence.

Comment: If $0<(x+\pi)<2\pi$ then $\frac{1}{((x+\pi)n)^2} > \frac{1}{4\pi^2 n ^2}$.

Comment: As $x \to -\pi+$, each term goes to $\infty$, so how could it possibly be uniform?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint. Note that for $x_n=-\pi+1/n$ we have that
 $$\frac{1}{((x_n+\pi)n)^2}=1.$$
On the other hand, when $x\in [a,\pi)$ for $a\in (-\pi,\pi)$,
$$0<\frac{1}{((x+\pi)n)^2}\leq \frac{1/(a+\pi)^2}{n^2}.$$

Comment: for the sequence $x_{n}$ mentioned the series diverges as we will be adding 1 infinite number of times, and for the $a$ in the next part the series converges so I am confused?

Comment: The second inequality means that we have uniform convergence in $[a,\pi)$ with any $a\in(-\pi,\pi)$. This does not imply that  we have uniform convergence also in $(-pi,\pi)$ (see my first remark).

Comment: $x_n$ is a sequence of points. right? How do you claim that series does not converge uniformly by plugging the countable points to different $f_n's$ rather than plugging some pont $x_0 \in (-\pi,\pi)$? Would you please explain?

Comment: @Mathgeek If $S_{N}=\sum_{n=1}^{N} \frac{1}{((x+\pi)n)^2}\to S$ converges uniformly  in $(-\pi,\pi)$ then $\sup_{x\in(-\pi,\pi)} |S_N-S_{N-1}|=\sup_{x\in(-\pi,\pi)} \frac{1}{((x_N+\pi)n)^2}$ goes to zero which is not by the above sequence.